# pyspark generate rdd row wise using another field as a source

Tags: pyspark, rdd

```
Input RDD
--------------------

A,123|124|125|126
B,123|124|125|126
```

From this rdd I need to generate another in the below format

```
Output RDD
--------------------
A,123
A,124
A,125
A,126
B,123
B,124
B,125
B,126
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = sc.parallelize([("a", ["x", "y", "z"]), ("b", ["p", "r"])])
def f(x): return x
x.flatMapValues(f).collect()
[('a', 'x'), ('a', 'y'), ('a', 'z'), ('b', 'p'), ('b', 'r')]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.